# How to "connect" String with a Boolean?

Tags: java, dictionary

I need to connect a `Boolean` and a `String`. I also need a `getter` and a `setter` for each `Boolean`.

For example:

```
boolean errorFlag1;
private static final String  errorMessage1 = "...";
boolean errorFlag2;
private static final String  errorMessage2 = "...";
...

public Messages[] getErrorMessages()
{
    if(errorFlag1)
         Add errorMessage1 to Messages[]
    if(errorFlag2)
         Add errorMessage2 to Messages[]
    ...
}


public boolean getErrorFlag1()
{
    return errorFlag1;
}
public setErrorFlag1( ef1 )
{ 
    this.errorFlag1 = ef1;
}
...
```

Could I use Map here? Is there a better way of "connecting" flag with a message?

Comment: How does errorMessage1 get set?  Is it a constant?

Comment: Yes, messages are constants.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (I hope i did not misunderstood your goal ):

```
enum ErrorMessage
{
    ERROR_ONE("First message"), ERROR_TWO("Second message");

    private String message; 

    ErrorMessage(String str) 
    {
        message = msg;
    }

    public String getMessage() 
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

This way you have constant error messages which contain a String as "message". Their type is `ErrorMessage`, and when you pass one like `ErrorMessage.ERROR_ONE` you can get their message by the getter method.

If you wish to have a class, which contains your errors, then you can create a collection of errors, and add or remove errors as they occured.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how your error messages are being set, but I would suggest storing an `Integer` representing each error in a `List<Integer>`.  Errors would be added to the `List` through an `addError` method which allows manipulation of the encapsulated list.

Then place the definition of your error messages within a `Map<Integer,String>`, whose key corresponds with the appropriate error message.  This will allow you to create new errors simply by adding a new entry in the map.

```
private List<Integer> errors = new ArrayList<Errors>();
private static Map<Integer> errorLookup = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

static{
  errorLookup.put(1, "Error Message 1");
  errorLookup.put(2, "Error Message 2");
}

public void addError(Integer errorKey){
   errors.add(errorKey);
}

public List<String> getErrors(){

   List<String> errorMsgs = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(Integer key: errors){
     errorMsgs.add(this.errorLookup.get(key).value);
   }
   return errorMsgs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map for sure,so that number of error messages are runtime determined. Use errormessage as key and boolean as value.

Comment: How do I implement getters and setters on a flag in case I use Map?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how they'd actually solve the problem using a `Map`, because I disagree with your assertion that a `Map` is actually usable here.

Comment: Map is useful only if no of error messages is previously unknown. So that is not a solution if you want getters for individual error messages.In that case I assume you know all possible errors, then you should use Enum as suggested in another answer